Is there a way to highlight certain class usage as a warning?
Is there a way to highlight certain class usage as a warning? For example I want to restrict usage of System.Math in my project. Can I somehow configure Rider or Roslyn to  make it underline all static methods calls of System.Math as warnings?

Typical scenario of Roslyn analyzer.

Regarding Roslyn, you can use the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers NuGet package.
To summarize from its documentation, after adding the package to your project/solution, add a BannedSymbols.txt to your project/solution and this to your csproj(s)
<ItemGroup>
  <AdditionalFiles Include="path to BannedSymbols.txt"/>
</ItemGroup>

Now you just need to fill BannedSymbols.txt.
One line should look like

{Documentation Comment ID string for the symbol}[;Description Text]

Given you're looking to get warnings for usage of a given class (System.Math), the first part should look like T:Namespace.Type which translates to T:System.Math for you case. The second part is optional and lets you customize the warning's message.
For example with T:System.Math; Use an other Math class instead, doing var x = System.Math.PI; will give you the following warning :

RS0030 : The symbol 'Math' is banned in this project: Use an other Math class instead


You may try to use External Annotations
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html#how_it_works
